# Are questions like "does modern knowledge (science, psychology,sociology etc. ) prove XYZ from scripture is false" allowed?

Tags: discussion

Is the factuality or otherwise of assertions in scripture sacred - regardless of what modern science science has to say about it?  for example - which is closer to the earth - the sun or the moon?

Comment: I don't have access to edit. :-(

Comment: Not allowed - see what happened to [a question on evolution](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24917) I asked sometime back. Asking if Vivekananda's followers now accept evolution to be true was sidelined by some comments questioning evolution itself. 'what modern science has to say' - users here will contest the scientific claims you cite. If you say Earth is round, a flat earther will refuse to accept it and downvote your post. If you cite Wikipedia some users will leave comments saying 'Wiki content is controlled by "Westerners" so can't be trusted'.

Comment: Is it "not allowed" on a case by case basis, or "not allowed", period?  In other words, factuality is not a factor to be brought up here? @sv.

Comment: Not allowed, period. “Does modern science prove Earth is flat from scripture false?” should be rephrased as "Modern science says Earth is round. What does Hindu scripture say about this?" then it becomes valid for this site. Facts on this site are limited to facts present in scripture.